# iPad version crashing

Tags: iphone

I am new to iOS development. I was opening the .xib file in the editor and tried to make an iPad version of the app. I went to File > Make iPad Version. An iPad UI appeared. I closed it and didn't save it.

The problem now is that the app is now crashing when viewed from an iPad.

Thanks!

Comment: what editor was that? you don't develop using xcode?

Comment: i develop using xcode. Sorry, I meant the interface Bulilder.
under menu > file, there is an option there to make an iPad version.

Comment: what version are you using? on 4.2 there is no "make" option. When I need to run the app on a device/simulator, I simply use the build/run command (or make an ipa, but that's not my job)

Comment: xCode Version 3.2.6
Interface Builder 3.2.6
Excact option is "Create iPad Version"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an official answer or, to be more precise, a couple of useful tips from someone who is also new to ios development (4 months):

First of all, update your xcode version. If you are new, there is absolutely no point in starting with an older version. True, it may have a bit more tutorials but it's not that hard to find stuff for xcode 4. Trust me, been there, done that ;)

Second, if you run your app on a device and it crashes, you will get a crash log. Connect the ipad to your pc and open the organizer window from xcode. There, go to Devices and select the logs for your device. The log will help you detect the cause of your problem.

Third, when you will encounter more problems like this in the future, be more detailed when asking for help on stackoverflaw. Post more info, error logs, print screens, etc. Basically, anything that could help others help you